# RTT in linux kernel: Unit

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, roundtrip

I am trying to getr the rtt value being used by the linux kernel. There I see two variable which are giving the rtt values:

srtt -- (smoothed RTT)
rcv_rtt_est, which is actually the Receiver side RTT estimation

Now, I actually dont see the units of these variable output. I think these re in jiffies and if i convert them to millisecs, the values got very low (almost zero).

So, I just want to get confirmed if these both value are in jiffies or in some other unit as i need to use them milliseconds and i am not getting the satisfactory output even if i use them directly or in msecs or microseconds.

I did not found anything i the comments of the code but i see a comment there which show the right shift by 3.

So, I used this following way to convert it to millisecs:

```
jiffies_to_msecs(tp->srtt >> 3))
```